# How to initialize WidgetInfo for unit testing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, widgetkit

I am trying to initialize the `WidgetKit` struct `WidgetInfo` for unit testing a function that takes `WidgetInfo` as an argument:

```
let widgetInfo = WidgetInfo()
```

This gives me the error:
*'WidgetInfo' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers*

I tried adding:

```
extension WidgetInfo {
    public init() {}
}
```

and I can initialize - yay! But then I try to set one of its properties

```
widgetInfo.family = .systemSmall
```

and get the error: *Cannot assign to property: 'family' is a 'let' constant*

I tried another initializer with arguments:

```
extension WidgetInfo {
    public init(family: WidgetFamily, kind: String) {
        self.family = family
        self.kind = kind
    }
}
```

and I get the error: *'let' property 'family' may not be initialized directly; use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead*

I'm stuck - is there a way for me to initialize `WidgetInfo`? Or another way to test a function that takes `WidgetInfo` as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I created a WidgetInfo protocol with the information I needed, changed the function to take the protocol as the argument and extended WidgetInfo:

```
protocol WidgetInfoProtocol {
    var widgetFamily: WidgetFamily { get }
    var widgetKind: String { get }
}

extension WidgetInfo: WidgetInfoProtocol {
    var widgetFamily: WidgetFamily {
        return family
    }

    var widgetKind: String {
        return kind
    }
}
```

This allowed me to create a mock for use in unit testing:

```
struct MockWidgetInfo: WidgetInfoProtocol {
    var widgetFamily: WidgetFamily
    var widgetKind: String
}
```